# How to set up Django Models for a Chat Room?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create an app where users can subscribe to rooms and send posts to each other, like a chatroom.

My thoughts where the following:

- Users can have multiple Groups.
- Rooms can have multiple users and Posts.
- Posts have one User as their author and can be posted in multiple
  Rooms at once.

```
class Room(models.Model):
    roomname = models.CharField(max_length=6)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rooms = models.ManyToManyField(Room)
```

What is the best way to set up the Django models, How can I add a relation between the user and the rooms in my models ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Chat Room Permissions Rules:**

1. A user can subscribe to many rooms, a room can be linked to
   many users.
2. A message can belong to one user only, but a user may have
   many messages.
3. A room may contain many messages from different
   users.

---

```
class Room(models.Model):
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True) #(1)
    name = models.CharField(...)
    ...

class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #(2)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #(3)
    message = CharField(...)
    ...
```

> **Note:** This model structure is taken from [Django-Chatrooms](https://github.com/qubird/django-chatrooms/blob/master/chatrooms/models.py)

From there you can customize your rooms, make it private or limit the access to *n* people, etc...

You can always fetch existing projects and easily get inspiration from their repositories.